# jqgrid click select all, but not all of them selected

Tags: jqgrid-php

I use jqgrid with multiple selection.  When i clicked select all for a multiple rows data, not all of them automatically checked. What was wrong with this?

If my grid has only one row, select all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root reasons is that the there are duplicated row id in json data. Following example show that there exists the duplicated row id  for 2 and 3. One the first of the duplicated row id will be selected when select all.

{"page":"1","total":"1","records":"10","rows":[
{"id":"10","cell":["firstaceha","Evebdfg","5","10","2000-01-30","12:30","notesss"]},{"id":"9","cell":["firstaceh","Evebdfg","7","9","2000-01-30","12:30","notesss"]},

{"id":"2","cell":["firsta","Eve","1","2","2000-01-30","12:30","notesss"]},{"id":"2","cell":["firsta","Eve","9","2","2000-01-30","12:31","notesss"]},

{"id":"3","cell":["firsta","Eveb","6","3","2000-01-30","12:30a","notesss"]},{"id":"2","cell":["firsta","Eve","8","2","2000-01-30","12:30ab","notesss"]},

{"id":"2","cell":["firsta","Eve","2","2","2000-01-30","12:30a","notesss"]},{"id":"3","cell":["firsta","Eveb","10","3","2000-01-30","12:30aa","notesss"]},

{"id":"3","cell":["firsta","Eveb","4","3","2000-01-30","12:30","notesss"]},{"id":"1","cell":["first","Eve","3","1","2000-01-30","12:30","notesss"]}]}